# solve one variable in a system of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a system of linear equations. Is there a condition on coefficients which ensures that one variable has a unique solution? I am looking for something similar to but weaker than full rank.

Comment: Do you mean a particular variable, or at least one variable?

Comment: Either way helps.

Comment: A system of linear equations will either have a unique solution, or a line of solutions, or some multi-dimensional space of solutions.  It is highly unlikely to have one variable fixed.